# how to see which line caused warning in PHP

Tags: php, debugging

I am using a code where code is in code.php and the user defined functions are stored in function.php.
The functions are called multiple times.

While executing the code in code.php - I got the following error message.

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SanskritVerb\function.php on line 1177
```

the line 1177 of function.php falls inside a user defined function 'ends'.
How can I know which line of code.php called this function 'ends' ?

I think some languages show error like - Error in line X of function.php called in line Y of code.php

If something of this sort exists for PHP - it would save my debug time.

Comment: Please show the relevant code

Comment: do you have any code? aka post the relevant lines

Comment: Your stack trace should give more information. Is this your entire error message? Also as asked, show us the function in question. And also, what's calling the function from your code file.

Comment: how many times ends() function is called from code.php files? check for the values passed in that function for all those instances

Comment: The relevant code is around 1 MB. function ends() is called 211 times in the code. So I am a bit confused which ends is faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a task you need to assign an error handler and call

> `Exception::getTrace()`

to get trace of `Exception`. see the documentation [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Using xdebug extension for PHP can give you higher tracing capabilities even without error. If you choose xdebug you should enable tracing by adding lines to php.ini

`xdebug.auto_trace=On
xdebug.trace_output_dir=c:\path`

Anyway this is up to you.

Comment: Seems like quite a lot of work for me to catch up with error-handler and Trace.

Comment: set-error-handler did the trick for me. Now can get the nearest errors and reduce the span for testing.